# Event does not work using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

```
<div id="form">
<form action="">
<input type="button" id="sub"/>
</form>
</div>
```

When clicking the submit button content will be changed using jquery.

Jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#sub').live('click', function() {
        var reg = "<form action=''><input type='text' id='text'/><input type='button' is='sub2'/></form>";
        $('#form').replaceWith(reg);
    });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#sub2').live('click', function() {
        $('#text').text("Some content");
    });
});
```

But my problem is the content does not get written into input box. How can i do that plz help? **Also how to change the background color of input box with id text?**

Comment: `is='sub2'` typo or is your code using `is` instead of `id`?

Comment: **Thanks to all for answering me**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But my problem is the content does not get written into input box.

You need to call `val()` instead of `text()` as text() is not defined for input type of text.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#sub2').live('click', function () {
      $('#text').val("Some content");
   });
});
```

Comment: Ok that worked...But can u say how to change the background color also?

Comment: You can do that by, `$('#yourControlId').css('background-color', 'red');`

Answer (score 2):

Your code contains syntax errors. You use double quotes inside the `var reg = "...";` string (`action=""`) which need to be escaped or written as `'`

You also need to use `.val()` to get/set the value of an input element instead of `.text()`

There is also no reason to use two document ready functions - just put everything in the same one.

Last but not least, `live()` is deprecated; use `on()` instead (see the jQuery docs on how to use it properly)